# Запуск bat-файла из Java

Tags: java, bat

Как запустить *bat-файл* из программы на *java*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c FullFileName.bat");
```

Вместо `FullFilePath.bat` вставляете полный/относительный путь к вашему bat-файлу, например: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c D:/BatFileName.bat");`

---

Если вам потребуются какие-то особые параметры запуска *bat-файла* (вместо `/c`), то посмотрите список параметров данной комманды в коммандной строке (`cmd /?`).

Comment: а как прочесть ответ ?

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "pathToYourFile.bat");
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"\" MyFile.bat");
```

Примечание: Файл должен хранится в папке с проектом и назваться `MyFile.bat.`